# criar funçao JavaScript para vários ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('div#bloqueioSelect').click(function() {

    if ($('div#bloqueioSelect ul').is(':visible')) {
      $('div#bloqueioSelect ul').css('display', 'none');
      $('div#bloqueioSelect div img').prop('src', 'imgs/setaBaixo.jpg');
    } else {
      $('div#bloqueioSelect ul').css('display', 'block');
      $('div#bloqueioSelect div img').prop('src', 'imgs/setaCima.jpg');
    }

  });

  $('div#bloqueioSelect ul li').click(function() {
    $('input[type=hidden]#bloqueio').val($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div.selecao {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao div {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selecao div,
div.selecao ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

div.selecao div * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.selecao div label {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div.selecao ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  /*Menos 1 pixel da borda*/
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao ul li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

div.selecao ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=hidden value='' name=bloqueio id=bloqueio />

<div class=selecao style='width: 150px;' id=bloqueioSelect>
  <div><label>Bloqueio</label><img src="imgs/setaBaixo.jpg" /></div>
  <ul>
    <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" title="Produto Bloqueado" /></li>
    <!--
  -->
    <li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" title="Produto Desbloqueado" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Tenho esse **código** que estilizei um select.

Nesse **código** existe um **JavaScript** para **popular** um **input hidden**

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de generalizar essa função de forma tal que eu não necessite de fazer uma chamada caso eu crie **vários** **id's** para os **selects**.

Exemplo: esse código só vai funcionar para o **id=bloqueioSelect**.

Caso eu tenho outro select, por exemplo: **id=cidadeSelect**, não vai funcionar.

Ou será que existe algum recurso sem a necessidade de fazer a chamada no próprio campo?

```
<div class=selecao style='width: 150px;' id=bloqueioSelect  onclick='funcao();'>
```

Era isso que estava querendo evitar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `class` ao invés de adicionar `id` para cada elemento. As `class` podem ser utilizadas várias vezes na página.

Sabendo onde foi o clique você pode navegar pelos elementos até encontrar o que precisa, por exemplo em `$(this).parents('.customSelect').find("input").val($(this).val());`,
essa linha procura dentro dos pais do elemento clicado, um com class `customSelect` e depois tenta achar um input dentro desse elemento, localizando assim o input escondido e setando o valor.

Basicamente existe sim como generalizar, basta utilizar classes e navegar pelos elementos com base no elemento clicado para identificar qual o elemento correspondente que deseja alterar.

OBS: Utilize aspas nos atributos do html, apesar de não ser obrigatório, evita muitos problemas com navegadores desatualizados.
OBS2: Existem problemas com o css, fica por sua conta.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.customSelect').click(function() {

    if ($(this).find('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find('div img').prop('src', 'imgs/setaBaixo.jpg');
    } else {
        $(this).find('ul').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).find('div img').prop('src', 'imgs/setaCima.jpg');
    }

  });

  $('.customSelect ul li').click(function() {
    //Seta o procura pelo input dentro do parent com a class "customSelect"
    $(this).parents('.customSelect').find("input").val($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div.selecao {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao div {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selecao div,
div.selecao ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

div.selecao div * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.selecao div label {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div.selecao ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  /*Menos 1 pixel da borda*/
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao ul li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

div.selecao ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

div.selecao ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="selecao customSelect" style='width: 150px;' id=bloqueioSelect>
  <input type=hidden value='' name=bloqueio id=bloqueio />
  <div><label>Bloqueio</label><img src="imgs/setaBaixo.jpg" /></div>
  <ul>
    <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" title="Produto Bloqueado" /></li>
    <!--
  -->
    <li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" title="Produto Desbloqueado" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="selecao customSelect" style='width: 150px;' id=cidadeSelect>
  <input type=hidden value='' name=cidade id=cidade />
  <div><label>Bloqueio</label><img src="imgs/setaBaixo.jpg" /></div>
  <ul>
    <li value=1><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" title="Produto Bloqueado" /></li>
    <!--
  -->
    <li value=0><img src="imgs/desbloquear.png" title="Produto Desbloqueado" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bom. Vamos lá: 1) Você usou customSelect mas poderia ter usado selecao? Se sim, porrque não usou° 2) Senão, porque ao usar customSelect não afetou as setas  dos 2 selcts?

Comment: 1. Sim, poderia. Preferi não usar pois achei que "selecao"  não estava expressando bem o que o elemento representa. Mas é questão de gosto mesmo. 2. Porque ao clicar na `<div>` eu busco os elementos relativos à ele e não na tela toda: significa "dentro desse elemento que eu cliquei(`$(this)`) encontre tal elemento (`find(...)`)

Comment: Sim. Mas tecnicamente, div.customSelect, ambas as div's são. Isto e, tem a mesma class. Porque o clike não afetou ambas? Isto é, porque ao clicar em uma div, o input da outra também não recebeu o valor? Essa e a dúvida!

Comment: Você quer dizer, porque ao clicar em uma não afeta outra? Ou  o click não está funcionando em alguma delas pra vc?

Comment: Seguinte: Você colocou .customSelect nas 2 divs. Certo? Se ambas são .customSelect, penso que, ao vlicar em uma, a outra também deveria acionar o JQuery e por consequência seu input também receberia o value. Mas não é isso que ocorre. Ants, e corretamente, apena o input da div licada recebe o valor. Não entendi porque o input da outra não recebeu também o valor sendo que ambas as  são .customSelect. Esse era o motivo de ei ter usado id ao invez de class

Comment: O motivo é o mesmo que eu falei antes...  Ao clicar na `$('.customSelect ul li')` 
 o evento é disparado e a partir dele eu procurei o input: `$(this).parents('.customSelect').find("input").val($(this).val());`  Isso significa: "Procure o `.customSelect` pai desse `li` que eu cliquei e depois ache um input dentro dele e adicione o valor." O "segredo" está no `$(this).parents(...)`

Comment: Entendi. Mas me correja se eu estiver errado. Quando clicamos em um elemento, $( 'div#bloqueioSelect' ).click( function () {} tudo que estiver dentro dele e que for refrenciado por $(this), ainda que exista outra div com a mesma classe, ela não receberá a ação  pelo fato de que this apenas referencia ao elemento clicado ao passo que se eu procurar uma ul dentro dessa div dessa forma $( 'div#bloqueioSelect ul' ).css( 'display', 'none' );, isso vai procurar no documento todo e não somente dentro da div class bloqueioSelect QUE FOI clicada. Acertei?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Exatamente isso.

Comment: Obrigado amigo@